# Lightning Flow - Update record element started hitting Limit Too many query rows: 50001 even with option - Use the case record that triggered the flow

Tags: servicecloud, lightning-flow-builder, salesforce-flow

We have an 'after record is created or updated' record triggered flow on Case, I have this flow to update the Case->AccountId with Case->Contact->AccountId.

Attached screenshot of the flow, and a screenshot of the issue element where the flow hits the limit error:

[image: Flow]

[image: Flow-Element]

> Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: LIMIT_EXCEEDED: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

This limit is hitting, while we receive Email-to-Case requests specifically from one email: SuppliedEmail=batchjob@xxxxx.com For the rest of the cases, it is working fine.

I am not sure, but just for confirmation is this issue because of:

> Email bounced. Update the email address and try

[image]

This error suddenly started on 2-Dec-2023. Before that, it was working fine.

Comment: Looks like recursion ! If you are updating the fields on same record which is triggering the flow, then why its a after save? It should be Fast field update (Before save) right?

Comment: Hi @VivekM, Thank you for your comment. Actually, this flow was converted from Process Builder. I was under the impression that the contact allocation to Case would be after Case creation in Email-to-Case and I may not get ContactId in the Fast Field Update, so I did not change it to the Fast Field Update. Now I changed it and it is working. But I am still surprised, this element can reach this limit! Recursion can lead to DML, SOQL limit, but the Update element with triggered record can hit Too many query rows limit of 50001! Specifically, hitting this limit for one service & supplied email.

Comment: Will have to check more on the data to see why this is happening only for one email  domain. 50k limit is an overall per-transaction limit, please check if there is any other trigger or flow on the same object.   
 I have added the same as answer, please mark the answer as right if it helped you  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, If you are updating the fields on same record which is triggering the flow, then you should use Fast field update (Before save).
Here the after save flow is causing recursion and causing to hit limits.